# LaTeX doesn't create new pages of bibliography or in the verbatim

Tags: bibliographies, verbatim

It seems that I have some inherent problem in my document and I don't even know what the problem can be and where to search...

When I create a bibliography using `\bibliography{bibliography}` LaTeX tries to put all sources on one page although there should be 2 pages. I changed `.bbl`-file and add `\newpage` there and it worked but it is still strange why LaTeX doesn't make bibliography properly. I already used this bibliostyle and it worked in other documents.

I wrote a long text in the

```
\begin{verbatim}

code code code

\end{verbatim}
```

This text was so long that didn't fit one page and again, LaTeX tried to put everithing in this one page and didn't create a new page.

What can be wrong? What should I check?

[image: This is a part of my 23th page]

Comment: [Welcome to SE.TeX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Could you please include a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: Though it is pretty clear why a verbatim environment won't break, it is not clear for a bibliography and probably those things are completely unrelatd ... voting to close as unclear after two years.